# Failed to start job for vncserver@1.service

Tags: raspbian, server, vnc, raspi-config, raspbian-jessie

I am trying to install tightvncserver and run it at boot. I tried various options, but none of them worked with raspbian `Jessie` version. But i found a post that [explained the process of creating a systemd service for Jessie raspbian release](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=123457&p=830506). However, i tried to follow the process and added a file named `vncserver@.service` with no issues. But, when i try to test if its working, i get following error -

> Job for vncserver@1.service failed. See 'systemctl status
>   vncserver@1.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

[Here is a gist of those commands](https://gist.github.com/girishsortur/59d10afbd1e1057234c5). How do i resolve this issue and make sure that vncserver starts without any issues. Thanks